# Connect iPad/iPhone to WiFI, but not MBP?

Tags: wifi

I have an iPhone and iPad that have permission to connect to WiFi W (Work).  I have a MiFi device (M), and I want my MacBook Pro to connect to M **and not W**.  How can I do this?  It seems that when Apple remembers a WiFi password (e.g., for W), it does it for all your Apple devices, including laptops.

Answer (score 1):

Click the Apple on your MBP and select System Preferences... and then choose Network.

Click Advanced at the bottom and WiFi should be highlighted. In that is Preferred Networks. Select the work on and hit the - to remove it. Then connect to the MiFi and in that same area, click the +.

Should be all set then!

Comment: When I click that, it says: "Remove Wi-Fi network "W"? Your Mac and other devices using iCould Keychain will no longer join this Wi-Fi network."  If I click this on my Mac, it will forget it for all my devices.  If I re-enter the password on the iPhone/iPad, it will remember it again for the MBP, which is not what I want.

Comment: Ah! Ok then, assuming you have both networks in that list, put the MiFi one at the top of the list and the W one at the bottom. At least it will go for the MiFi first every time.

Comment: That's what I've done, based on your suggestion.  Actually I put M at the top of the list and I deleted W from the list.  Your suggestion may work, but I really wish it were possible to configure this per-device.  Work DOES NOT want my laptop on the network, but it doesn't mind the iPhone/iPad on a specific network they said it was OK to connect to.  Also, I DON'T WANT the iPad/iPhone connecting to the MiFi device.  That is for the laptop only.

Comment: The only option would be to decouple from iCloud and put what you need on the MBP. I agree that it should allow more granular control but Apple tends to make things unified based on the theory that convergence is king and why wouldn't you want that. Sorry... I don't use the iCloud keychain for that reason.  For regular passwords, I use LastPass as my access everywhere storage.

Answer (score 1):

Short of asking them to simply blacklist your MAC address on the work network…

You'll have to remove one device or the other from iCloud Keychain. On the Mac or iPhone, go to System Preferences > iCloud and deselect Keychain. Then when you remove the Wi-Fi network on your Mac, it will not affect the iPhone.

Comment: I upvoted your answer @samh because you know what you're talking about, not because I like this all-or-nothing approach of Apple's.

Comment: Indeed. I understand Apple's thinking—granular control over potentially thousands of keychain items is a difficult UX problem to solve.

Comment: @gknauth there is one other possibility that occurred to me—they could simply blacklist your Mac's MAC address at work so that it is disallowed on the Wi-Fi altogether.

Comment: Yeah, they could do that.  But I'm hoping not to be on anyone's bad list.  You could work out something with today's IT guy, only to have it become a problem with the next one.